# Dual boot: how many IP addresses?

Tags: networking, ip

If I have a dual boot machine (Windows and Linux), and my network administrator assigns me a static IP address, will I get two addresses, or one? Or is it up to the administrator's discretion? What are the advantages of each approach?

Thanks!

Comment: static IP has some advantage and DHCP has some advantage, it's related to circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are dual booting you will only be using one IP address at the time, so it can be the same one on both operating systems.

The network administrator might assign two different IP addresses to you if so they desire, but it really poses no advantage, save for really specific situations such as running two different servers for the same service under the two OS's and needing to be able to discern the two.

Generally however one IP is assigned to one machine regardless of what OS is running on it.

Answer (score 0):

He can set two Ip's but one is enough because you're not going to use them simultaneously